# Creating a button that makes this specific function (html, css)

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, modal-dialog

im making an website and im working on a modal on one of it's pages that have a text like:

John: 894824

I want to make a button that will show that text above only when i trigger it.

I was reading something other day that had something related to this, but more like pressing a button and making a box slide and appear. That's the kind of thing i want to do here. If anyone understands my problem and are able to help with this i would appreciate a lot.

Thanks

```
<div class="modal modal_quero_contratar modal-xs fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"> Você tem certeza que deseja contratar este serviço? </h4>
  </div>

    <div class="modal-body">        

        <p class = "modal_texto1"> Se você optar por contratar, será solicitada uma availiação sua sobre o serviço prestado. </p>
        <p> Abaixo seguem as informações de contato: </p>
        <p class="servico_email_contato">  </p>
        <p class="servico_cel_contato">  </p>
        <p class="servico_telefone_contato">  </p>
        <br>
        <p> Este quebra-galho foi também salvo no seu painel! </p>


    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: sure, it's not very helpful i think but maybe you can figure out something

Comment: there it is, i just edited with the code in

Comment: Have you wrote any JS to accompany this HTML yet?

Answer (score 0):

This needs bootstrap and here's the code

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal modal_quero_contratar modal-xs fade" id="modal" role="dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"> Você tem certeza que deseja contratar este serviço? </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

      <p class="modal_texto1">Se você optar por contratar, será solicitada uma availiação sua sobre o serviço prestado.</p>
      <p>Abaixo seguem as informações de contato:</p>
      <p class="servico_email_contato"></p>
      <p class="servico_cel_contato"></p>
      <p class="servico_telefone_contato"></p>
      <br>
      <p>Este quebra-galho foi também salvo no seu painel!</p>


    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
    </div>


  </div>
```